# Border values in table overwrite neighbours

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-allocation

I am writing a C program, in which I try to dynamically allocate a 2-dim array (or an array of arrays.) After the table is allocated I try to iterate over it, but it throws an error about illegal memory access and creates a coredump.

After some investigation I've found out a curious thing: **the array I experiment with is 4x4, but when I set `array[0][3] = 123;` it sets both [0][3] and [1][0] positions to be 123.** Exactly the same thing happens if I assign `array[1][0] = 123;`, as it sets both [0][3] and [1][0] to the rightside value. Similar assignment is done for any "border values", like [2][0] and [1][3]. I guess something must be wrong with my allocation, but I can't figure it out. I was pretty sure that this is the way to dynamically allocate multi-dim arrays and a bit of research confirmed it. Here is my code (I know it should be SSSCE but I can't provide it shorter and still show the problem):

```
typedef struct {
    int rows;
    int columns;
    double **data;
} matrix;


matrix* allocateMatrix(int inputRows, int inputColumns) {
    matrix *matrixPointer = calloc(1, sizeof(matrix));
    matrixPointer->rows = inputRows;
    matrixPointer->columns = inputColumns;
    #ifdef DOUBLE
        matrixPointer->data = calloc(inputRows, sizeof(double*));
    #else
        matrixPointer->data = calloc(inputRows, sizeof(float*));
    #endif
    if (matrixPointer->data == NULL) {
        printf("Error - inputRows value appears to be wrong.");
        return NULL;
    }

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < inputRows; i++) {
    #ifdef DOUBLE
        matrixPointer->data[i] = calloc(inputColumns, sizeof(double));
    #else
        matrixPointer->data[i] = calloc(inputColumns, sizeof(float));
    #endif
        if (matrixPointer->data[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Error - inputColumns value appears to be wrong.");
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    matrixPointer->data[2][0] = 123;    //TEST CODE;

    return matrixPointer;
}
```

And some code to see the contents of such created array:

```
matrix *lol = allocateMatrix(4, 4); 
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < lol->rows; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < lol->columns; j++)
                printf("%f ", lol->data[i][j]);
```

Is my memory allocation wrong, or maybe some other issue I fail to see. I would be grateful for any suggestions or help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Man, after not finding any clear mistake in your code, I decided to run it. It works just fine.
Make sure you're compiling and testing the latest version of your code. If it doesn't solve, there might be a "problem" with your compiler

Comment: Run it again today an no progress. As this is academic stuff, I am compiling it with GCC. Still, setting array[1][0] to 123 sets both [1][0] and [0][3] to 123...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct {
    int rows;
    int columns;
    double **data;
} matrix;
```

This is the culprit. The DOUBLE macrodefinition was supposed to enable double precision through the code, but when the flag was not set the code still allocated `double** data`, causing possible segmentation faults. The correct code in this case should look like:

```
typedef struct {
    int rows;
    int columns;
    #ifdef DOUBLE
        double **data;
    #else
        float **data;
    #endif
} matrix;
```